# Pandas stock dataframe , initialize a counter in a columns on a condition met (ORB, NR4/7)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have some code which downloads stock price data from Yahoo finance. I want to create some sort of distribution statistics for so called "narrow ranges in a given time period - (which lead to expansion bars). Mostly for the narrowst range in 4 or 7 days. After marking those narrow ranges with 'NR7' or 'NR4' - preferably in only column - I want to start a counter which starts with every 'NR'  with 1 and they next day increases by 1 so that´s 2 on the second day, after the 'NR' occured, 3 on the third and so on...

I tried to realize it in the vectorized code for defining a narrow range. Look at the code for df['Bars2NR']. It doesn´t work this way bc it´s self referencing? What options would you prefer to realize a renewed counter on every new 'NR'?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance 

#download stock price time series data
Ticker = 'MSFT' 
df = yfinance.download(Ticker , start='2022-01-01',  end='2022-09-17' )

#Calculate basic indicators / moving averages
df['SMA10'] = df['Close'].rolling(10).mean()
df['ADR20'] = ((df['High'].rolling(20).mean()/df['Low'].rolling(20).mean())-1)*100
df['ADR1'] = (df['High']/df['Low']-1)*100
df['Range'] = df['High']-df['Low']
df['OCRange'] = abs(df['Open']-df['Close'])
BarFillThreshold = 0.75
df['TrendBar'] = df['OCRange']/df['Range'] > BarFillThreshold
df['Bars2NR'] = 0

#Define narrow range bars (smallest of last 7 or 4 bars)
df['NR7'] = np.where((df.Range < df.Range.shift()) & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-1))
                     & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-2)) & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-3))
                     & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-4)) & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-5))
                     & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-6)), 'NR7', '')

#Narrow Range Bar 4 (in days)
df['NR4'] = np.where((df.Range < df.Range.shift()) & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-1))
                     & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-2)) & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-3))
                     , 'NR4', '')

df['Bars2NR'] = np.where((df.Range < df.Range.shift()) & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-1))
                     & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-2)) & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-3))
                     & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-4)) & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-5))
                     & (df.Range < df.Range.shift(-6)), 1, df.Bars2NR.shift(1)+2 )' <--- '
#Every time there is a new NR4 or NR7 a new count start with 1 should start

df['RangeExpansion'] =np.where((df.ADR1 > df.ADR20), 1, 0)


df.tail(50)
```

Comment: After reading a bit I came across with the following idea. I introduced a column filled with '1' and creating for each NR7/4 an ID. This helped me to use .cumsum function to calculate the day count ( df['Bars2NRDistance'] ). These are the additional code lines: ` df.loc[df['NR7'] == 'NR7', 'NR_ID'] = round((df['Low']+df['High']+df['Close'])*1000)
 df['NR_ID'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

 df['Bars2NRDistance'] = df.groupby(['NR_ID'])['Bars2NR'].cumsum()`

Comment: Does somebody have a better idea? It clearly works, so I am satisfied. I had some issue with creating the NR_ID. With the np.where I used random numbers. Unfortunately it put in a random number into the rows but for all flagged 'NR7/4 the same. That´s why I created it with the sum of Low, High, Close...